# Query Taking a lot of time to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, which is taking more than 3 minutes to execute. I have also posted the explain plan. What should I do to reduce the execution time? Is it taking more time because of the left joins?

```
SELECT d.name as doc, SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN bill_type = 'registration' AND bop.particulars = 'Consultation Fee' THEN bop.amount
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'op',


    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN bill_type = 'casuality' THEN b.payable_amount
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'cas' ,

    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN bill_type = 'pharmacy' THEN b.payable_amount
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'ph', 

    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN bill_type = 'lab' THEN b.payable_amount
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'lab' ,
    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN bill_type = 'xray' THEN b.payable_amount
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'x' ,
    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN bill_type = 'audiology' THEN b.payable_amount
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'au',
    SUM(
        CASE 
        WHEN bill_type = 'discharge' THEN b.payable_amount + IFNULL(w.balance, 0)
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'ip'


    FROM bills b 

    LEFT JOIN patient_wallet w on w.id =  (SELECT x.id FROM patient_wallet x WHERE x.ip_id = b.ip_id ORDER BY x.created_at DESC  LIMIT 1)
    LEFT JOIN bill_contents_op bop on bop.bill_id = b.id
    LEFT JOIN doctors d on d.id = b.doctor_id
    WHERE b.doctor_id IN(41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80) AND CAST(b.created_at AS DATE) >= '2016-06-01' AND CAST(b.created_at AS DATE) <= '2016-06-30' AND b.is_cancelled = 0 AND b.is_deleted = 0 GROUP BY d.name
```

The explain plan is as follows.

```
1
PRIMARY
b
NULL
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
161351
0.50
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1
PRIMARY
w
NULL
eq_ref
PRIMARY
PRIMARY
4
func
1
100.00
Using where
1
PRIMARY
bop
NULL
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
124490
100.00
Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1
PRIMARY
d
NULL
eq_ref
PRIMARY
PRIMARY
4
santhwana.b.doctor_id
1
100.00
NULL
2
DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
x
NULL
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
78
10.00
Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Does it run fast when you select * ?

Comment: yes. took just 14 seconds ( Showing rows 0 - 24 (8633 total, Query took 14.0198 seconds. )

Comment: so you should check you MySQL server configuration. Also you sould check indexes of the columns inside where clause, if they do not have indexes and contains huge data its where clause will be costy.

Comment: You are missing some indexes: `bill_contents_op(bill_id)`, `patient_wallet x(ip_id)`, `bills(doctor_id)`. `created_at` should be a `datetime`-column, not a `varchar`(or whatever it is). Your `left join` to `patient_wallet` is inefficient, but since this table is small, it might not have a big effect to optimize it. Can your comment out that join (and your last sum) to see if it would change the execution (or if the code can stay like that).

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare . I've added those indexes and the execution time is reduced to a few seconds. And, there's not much difference in time after commenting out the patient_wallet join. 

Also, created_at is not datetime but timestamp. Is that wrong?

Comment: No, timestamp is fine, I just thought because you casted the column to `date`. Then you can add an even better index: `bills(doctor_id, created_at)`, and replace `and CAST(b.created_at AS DATE) >= '2016-06-01' AND CAST(b.created_at AS DATE) <= '2016-06-30'` by `and b.created_at between '2016-06-01' and '2016-06-30 23:59:59'. This should give you another boost.